# Why does my function only keep one dictionary key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d = {}
while True: 
    group_name = input("Enter group name (empty to cancel): ")
    if len(group_name) == 0:
        print('')
        break
    else:
        d.[group_name] = {}
        while True:
            field_name = input("Enter field name (empty to stop): ")
            if len(field_name) == 0:
                print('')
                break
            else:
                global d_list
                d[group_name]['_keys_'] = []
                d[group_name]['_keys_'].append(field_name)
```

Whenever I try to add multiple items in `group_name` or in `field_name`, it only keeps the last one I entered in the `input()`. How can I make so that I can have multiple `group_names` or `field_names`?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you clear it every time you want to append anything: `d[group_name]['_keys_'] = []`

Comment: I only see one problem. you are re-initializing `__keys__` for every parameter. the line `d[group_name]['_keys_'] = []`

Comment: d.[group_name] = {} this syntax is wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys, I see what you're talking about. How do i just create a new one each time instead of clearing it?

Comment: Where does `dict[][_keys_]` come from? I don’t think I’ve ever seen that before.

Comment: If you want to check whether the input string is empty or not, just do `if input_str:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code resets the list instead of properly checking for the right condition before doing that. It would also reset an entire `group_name`: if you were to re-enter the same `group_name` to add more fields, it wouldn't work, you'd lose your old entries.

To fix that, the code below initializes a `group_name` key only if it wasn't there before. Similarly, it will only initialize the empty list the very first time (when `__keys__` wasn't there), letting you to append other entries and keeping them.

Below a commented version of the code:

```
d = {}
while True:
    group_name = input("Enter group name (empty to cancel): ")
    if len(group_name) == 0:
        print('')
        break
    else:
        if group_name not in d:
            # only initialize a new group_name key
            d[group_name] = {}

        while True:
            field_name = input("Enter field name (empty to stop): ")
            if len(field_name) == 0:
                print('')
                break
            else:
                global d_list
                # similarly, only initialize if not there already
                if '_keys_' not in d[group_name]:
                    d[group_name]['_keys_'] = []
                d[group_name]['_keys_'].append(field_name)
```

One sample run:

```
Enter group name (empty to cancel): alfa
Enter field name (empty to stop): a
Enter field name (empty to stop): b
Enter field name (empty to stop): c
Enter field name (empty to stop): 

Enter group name (empty to cancel): beta
Enter field name (empty to stop): d
Enter field name (empty to stop): e
Enter field name (empty to stop): f
Enter field name (empty to stop): 

Enter group name (empty to cancel): 

{'alfa': {'_keys_': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, 'beta': {'_keys_': ['d', 'e', 'f']}}
```